# Calculate length of service (days) with termination ranges removed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a dataset that looks like the table below. I need to calculate an employees total length of service while removing any time that they were Terminated (T in Status column). There can be duplicate Active records as the data shows.

Right now I can calculate their total days from start to finish with the following. However, I am looking for recommendations on how to subtract out the termination ranges. L's for Leave of absence are to be included.

```
SELECT EmpNo, DateDiff(dd, MIN(EffDate), getdate()) as LOS FROM JobHistory
WHERE EmploymentStatus = 'A'
Group By EmpNo
```

Doing some digging, I've come across the lag/lead option but wanted to reach out to the community as to whether this would be the most efficient way to go about it or not. Any recommendations or ideas are appreciated.

| EmpNo | EffDate | Status | EmploymentStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2018-12-10 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 001 | 2018-12-10 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 001 | 2018-12-12 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 001 | 2018-12-31 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 001 | 2019-10-15 00:00:00.000 | T | A |
| 001 | 2021-08-16 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 001 | 2021-11-15 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 001 | 2021-11-15 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 001 | 2021-12-08 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 001 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 001 | 2022-01-10 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 001 | 2022-03-11 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 001 | 2022-03-14 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 001 | 2022-05-09 00:00:00.000 | T | A |
| 001 | 2022-09-12 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 001 | 2022-10-10 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 001 | 2022-10-24 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 001 | 2023-02-20 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 002 | 2018-12-05 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 002 | 2018-12-05 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 002 | 2018-12-31 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 002 | 2019-08-31 00:00:00.000 | L | A |
| 002 | 2019-09-28 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 002 | 2019-09-29 00:00:00.000 | L | A |
| 002 | 2019-10-18 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 002 | 2019-10-21 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 002 | 2019-11-25 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 002 | 2019-11-25 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 002 | 2019-12-09 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 002 | 2019-12-30 00:00:00.000 | A | A |
| 002 | 2020-03-12 00:00:00.000 | T | A |
| 002 | 2022-01-17 00:00:00.000 | A | A |

The expected result would be the following with 5/7/2023 as the run date:

| EmpNo | LOS |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 811 |
| 002 | 938 |

Breakdown of the calculation:

EmpNo 001: 1609(first EffDate to 5/7/2023) - 670(terminated stint 1) - 128(terminated stint 2) = 811

EmpNo 002: 1615(first EffDate to 5/7/2023) - 677(terminated stint) = 938

Comment: can you send expected data with text?

Comment: You want duplicates to be deleted and when it reaches T, it is deleted and the sum of mirrors is calculated(example  : (2018-12-31 00:00:00.000- 2018-12-10 00:00:00.000) +( 2022-03-14 00:00:00.000-2021-08-16 00:00:00.000))??

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi - is the expected result helpful? Or were you asking for something else?

Comment: I ask you about your question